# Как получить значения массива без цикла?

Tags: php

Как получить значения массива без цикла?

Циклом получить нет проблем, но очень не устраивает скорость выполнения в несколько минут, нужно хотя бы сократить на несколько секунд

Массив отсортирован по ключу, ключ это время time()

```
$start = 21;
$end = 25;

/* Пример исходного массива, может быть более миллиона значений
В реальности он гораздо сложнее и выполняется внутри небольших циклов */
$array = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]; 

/* Получить результат на основе $start и $end */
$result = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25];
```

Comment: Нечто вроде ```print_r(array_intersect($array, range($start, $end)));```, но на многомиллионном массиве данных это также не столь эффективное решение.

Comment: Что значит массив отсортирован по ключу. В нем сами значения идут по возрастанию как в примере ? И цель - найти сначала элемент со значением start, потом скопировать из массива все, пока не встретится элемент равный end ? Если да, то первый элемент ищется двоичным поиском (т.е. методом деления пополам), а после уже в цикле копируется нужный кусок пока не встретим end

Answer (score 2):

Если значения в массиве отсортированы, то самый простой способ, это что-то вроде этого:

```
function getRange(array $sortedArray, int $start, int $end): array
{
    $keyStart = array_search($start, $sortedArray);
        
    return array_slice(
        $sortedArray,
        $keyStart,
        array_search($end, $sortedArray) - $keyStart
    );
}
```